# How do you do a dry run of rm to see what files will be deleted?

Tags: file-management, rm

I want to see what files will be deleted when performing an `rm` in linux.  Most commands seem to have a dry run option to show just such information, but I can't seem to find such an option for `rm`.  Is this even possible?

Comment: I would also like to see which files will generate errors for lack of permissions.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Say you want to run:

```
rm -- *.txt
```

You can just run:

```
echo rm -- *.txt
```

or even just:

```
echo *.txt
```

to see what files `rm` would delete, because it's the shell expanding the `*.txt`, not `rm`.

The only time this won't help you is for `rm -r`.

If you want to remove files and directories recursively, then you could use `find` instead of `rm -r`, e.g.

```
find . -depth -name "*.txt" -print
```

then if it does what you want, change the `-print` to `-delete`:

```
find . -depth -name "*.txt" -delete
```

(`-delete` implies `-depth`, we're still adding it as a reminder as recommended by the GNU `find` manual).

Comment: find is a good choice IMO. And if you want a graphical presentation use `tree`.

Comment: Almost perfect. `find . -name "*.txt" -delete` doesn't seem to be recursive tho. Removed all the files, but didn't remove directories that were listed in `-print`

Comment: @OscarGodson Assuming the directories were left empty after removing the files, you can remove them with `find . -type d -empty -delete`

Comment: @OscarGodson - `find` will not delete directories that still contain files (equivalent to `rm dir/` without `-r`). You would have to empty the directory first - or use `find` to `-exec rm` with the appropriate options to do this. e.g. `find . -depth -name "*.txt" -exec rm -r {} +`

Comment: Using the `echo rm *.txt` method seems to have a drawback. It presents the results in a concatenated list (a long string with one file after the previous one), as opposed to a vertical list. Is there any way to get the output to display in a vertical list (one file per line) ? (UPDATE: I see that the `find` method does what I have requested. So I'll run with that.)

Comment: @inspirednz You could also use `printf "%s\n" *.txt`, or any similar variant.

Comment: Life suddenly makes sense!

Answer (score 30):

You can say:

```
rm -i
```

to run it in interactive mode, so `rm` will prompt you to confirm whether each file should be deleted. You could just answer no to each file to see which ones would be affected.

Comment: This is rather difficult with a large number of files.

Comment: yes n | rm -i #comment to meet minimum comment length

Answer (score 12):

You can use `ls` to list all the files that will be removed by `rm`:

```
ls ../path/*.txt
```

If you need to list to view the files that will be deleted with a recursive `rm`, then use the `-R` flag with `ls`:

```
ls -R ../path/*.txt
```

Comment: Good point. Though if you know the level of nesting then you can achieve this by `ls */*/*.txt`

Comment: You're right. With the `-R` option.

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to belatedly point out a handy solution that [Joshua mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7056/how-do-you-run-a-dry-run-of-rm-to-see-what-files-will-be-deleted#comment489006_7057) in the comments:

```
yes n | rm -i myFile1 myFile2 myFile3
```

This runs `rm` in interactive mode, which prompts a y/n response for each file it would delete, but via `yes n` it automatically declines this prompt for each file. The output isn't super pretty, but is parseable with a little cleanup.

Comment: Doesn't work for recursive rm because that asks for confirmation before descending into directories